# How to hide selected value from select option drop down

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

let's say with the select option(dropdown) on the visualforce page I have INDIA, USA, UK. if I select INDIA that should be displayed in visual force page and if I open again dropdown the selected value or displayed value on visualforce page, it should not display INDIA, it should display the only USA and the UK

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using javascript in your visualforce page.

you need to include a js file like this:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.MyJavascriptFile}"/>
```

Store the values as options like this:

```
    Options = [
        { label: '1', value: '1' },
        { label: '2', value: '2' },
        { label: '3', value: '3' },
        { label: '4', value: '4' },
    ];
```

Then your code need to detect a selected option you could do this like this:

```
var options = document.getElementsByName('{!$Component.foo}')
for(option in options)
  if(options[option].selected)
    alert('The selected value is: ' + options[option].value)
```

Once a value is selected you need to deleted from the option array like this:

```
let Selectedvalue = 3

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3]

arr = arr.filter(item => item !== value)
```

---